# Error 'React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.' with react-redux and Auth0

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, auth0

I have the following React initialization:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={config.domain}
      client_id={config.clientId}
      redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But I get an error message when I run this code that was originally create using CRA and modified as directed at the Auth0 site:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
initAuth0
.../src/react-auth0-spa.js:41
  38 |        setUser(user);
  39 |      }
  40 | 
> 41 |      setLoading(false);
     | ^  42 |    };
  43 |    initAuth0();
  44 |    // eslint-disable-next-line
View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Comment: Can you share `react-auth0-spa.js` where the error occurs

Comment: The text to too long. It is basically what is suggested on the Auth0 site.Here is the code right around the error:
`
      const isAuthenticated = await auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated();

      setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        const user = await auth0FromHook.getUser();
        setUser(user);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };
    initAuth0();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
`